# How can i make a "parameterized" JQL

Tags: jira

Is there any possibility to create a JQL query that can be parameterized with a specific value that can be selected by a user for a dashboard? For example, I wanna show all issues that are linked to a certain issue via a specific link type.
The query I use for links looks like this:

```
project = Bar and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOfRecursive("project = Foo and key = Foo-123", "relates to")
```

As you can see, the query itself is not the problem, its rather simple, but the key is hardcoded. Is there any way of creating a dashboard / rich filter, where the user can simply enter a key and the query is executed with that key?